# AWK display the line number of last match

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm new to AWK. Does anyone know how to print out the line number of last match of a file using awk.
Here's a small part of the Test.txt file content:

```
CLOSE #140,value=140
WAIT = #14039,value=143
CLOSE #140,value=144
WAIT #0,value=155
WAIT = #14039,value=158
CLOSE #140,value=160
```

This is the code I used so far
Success first line:

```
awk -F= '{if($NF >= 143 && $NF <= 158){print NR,exit}}' Test.txt
```

But for last line

```
awk -F= '{if($NF >= 143 && $NF <= 158){a=$0}} END{print a,NR}' Test.txt
```

It's only printed out the hold matching line and the last line number of the file. 
How can I get the line number of the last match?
Please help me with some advice.

Comment: Do you want the content as well as the line number, or just the line number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `a = NR` instead of `a = $0` (because it's the line number you want to remember, not the line itself).

Apart from that, it would arguably be more awkish to write

```
awk -F= '$NF >= 143 && $NF <= 158 { a = NR } END { print a }' Test.txt
```

`{if(){}}` is a bit ugly.

Comment: Thank so much for quickly replying! Can't believe, I didn't see it even it's right under my nose. I will use your recommend instead of the ugly {if(){}}

Comment: You might want `print a+0` to always print a number even when no lines match.